# Updating each element in collection MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, updating

I am trying to update each element of a collection, one at a time. My pseudocode is:

```
for e in myColl.find():
    # ...calculations involving variables of 'e'
    myColl.update({'_id':e['_id']}, { '$set': {'myvar':123}})
```

where `myvar` is a new variable added to `e`.

This update results in no change at all in the collection.

I imagine it is because the cursor is already looping through `myColl` and therefore cannot update inside the collection, but I don't know how to get around it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row in myColl.find():
    row['myvar'] = 123
    myColl.save(row)
```